# How can I create a txt file in xml using Sql server?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

How can i create the below xml file from sql server?

```
<Database>
<Tables>
<Table Name="Student"> <Files> <File FileName="Student_Info.txt" NumberOfRows="44" /> </Files>
<Columns>  
<Column Name="Name" DataType="nvarchar" Length="50" /> 
<Column Name="Department" DataType="nvarchar" Length="30" /> 
 <Column Name="Phone" DataType="nvarchar" Length="20" /> 
</Columns>  </Table> 
<Table Name="Teacher">
<Files>
<File FileName="Teacher.txt" NumberOfRows="33"  />
</Files>
<Columns>
<Column Name="TID" DataType="ANSI INTEGER" IsPrimaryKey="true" />
<Column Name="TName" DataType="ANSI CHARACTER VARYING" Length="50" />
</Columns>
</Table>
</Database>
```

Here I want to make a database where all table data will save in a txt file and the Number of rows will change everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query would give you the current database format output like what you have

```
select 
(
    select TABLE_NAME as '@Name' ,
        ( select COLUMN_NAME as '@Name',
               Data_type as '@DataType',
               character_octet_length as '@Length'
        FROM information_schema.COLUMNS C
        WHERE IT.TABLE_NAME =   C.TABLE_NAME
        FOR XML PATH ('Column'), TYPE
        ),
        (select 
            (  SELECT distinct  
                d.physical_name as '@FileName',
                i.rowcnt as '@NumberofRows'
                FROM    sys.sysindexes i,
                sys.filegroups f,
                sys.database_files d,
                sys.data_spaces s
                WHERE   OBJECTPROPERTY(i.id, 'IsUserTable') = 1
                AND f.data_space_id = i.groupid
                AND f.data_space_id = d.data_space_id
                AND f.data_space_id = s.data_space_id  
                AND IT.TABLE_NAME =   OBJECT_NAME(i.id) 
                FOR XML  path  ('File'), Type
            ) 
        FOR XML PATH ('Files'), Type
        )
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES IT
for xml path ('Table'), TYPE
)
for xml path ('Databases')
```

Comment: But it will not create the file name where all the data will save!

Comment: updated the query to give file name and number of rows.

Comment: there is a problem,when it executes under student table it shows all the column including teacher table also. for example:


`<Table Name="Student"> 
<Columns>  
<Column Name="Name" DataType="nvarchar" Length="50" /> 
<Column Name="Department" DataType="nvarchar" Length="30" /> 
 <Column Name="Phone" DataType="nvarchar" Length="20" /> 
<Column Name="TID" DataType="ANSI INTEGER" IsPrimaryKey="true" />
<Column Name="TName" DataType="ANSI CHARACTER VARYING" Length="50" />
</Columns>`

but it has to show only respective column of a particular table.

Comment: can you try now, added where clause to columns also

Comment: Data base has file groups ( logical entity ) and each file group has files ( physical file) and tables are created on a file groups. here we are finding the tables file group and then corresponding physical file location.